# How do I connect to the ManagedObjectContext object of the File Owner in XCode 4

Tags: cocoa, core-data, xcode4

I'm building a really simple Core Data app in XCode 4. There's an entity model with just one entity (Employee) and just one attribute (name).

In IB I've added a default Table View to display the employees, two buttons (one to add an employee and another to delete an employee) and an ArrayController.

It is my understanding that the ArrayController's managedObjectContext somehow needs to be connected to the one that is initialised by the App Delegate. I can see the code for initialising the context but IB does not let me connect to it.

How do I do this connection?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does Interface Builder not allow you connect it? Bindings are not the same as `IBOutlets` in Interface Builder context. If file owner is instance of `AppDelegate` (which always has initial managed object context) you just should define `NSArrayController`'s managedObjectContext binding's object as `File's owner` and set `managedObjectContext` as its model path.

Comment: I changed the following: set the File Owner class in the nib file to EmployeeDemoAppDelegate (which initialises the ManagedObjectContext instance). I added the binding for the Array Controller as per your answer. The binding now shows up under "Referencing Bindings" with the Array Controller. However, when I run the app it throws an exception: [<NSApplication 0x102300bf0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to bind explicitly to EmployeeDemoAppDelegate and not to File's Owner. Apparently there's a subtle difference which I'm unaware of. Thanks for your answer! Big help.

Comment: Didn't you have `App Delegate` object placeholder in the nib already? What is the name of the nib file?

Comment: See my comment above. The App Delegate placeholder was in the NIB. There's a subtle difference between the File's Owner and the actual class, apparently...